# Auto-antonyms in Latin

Tags: vocabulary, antonym

It seems there are no questions on this site about it because I can't search out.

An auto-antonym (also called contronym, antagonym, Janus word, etc.) is a word whose antonym can be itself. For example, *to dust* can be *to remove dust from*, but also *to make sth. dusty* (although tagged as "archaic" in the dictionary).

I can't find any detailed list on search engines.

Below are some possible types of auto-antonyms I found:

1. coincidences of different etymologies

> **invocātus**
>
> *that is called* (← **invocāre**) or
>
> *that is not called* (← **vocāre**)
> **victōrum**
>
> *of conquerers* (← **victor**) or
>
> *of conquered ones* (← **victus**)

2. from different ways of metaphor (?)

> **excipere**
>
> *to take out, to exclude* (by emphasizing **ex-**) or
>
> *to receive, to take in* (by emphasizing **capere**)
> **sinister**
>
> *auspicious, lucky* or *unlucky, improper* (due to the different augury customs between Romans and Greeks)
> **obēsus** (?)
>
> *lean, meagre* or *fat, coarse*

3. branching of good and bad senses of adjectives (e.g. *awful*)

> **sacer**
>
> *sacred, holy* or *accursed*

4. from translation; some concepts may be regarded as one but expressed by different foreign words 
   (e.g. German *leihen* and Chinese *jiè* are translated as either *to lend* or *to borrow*)

> **hospes**
>
>  *host* or *guest*
> **altus** (from FlatAssembler's comment)
>
>  *high, tall* or *deep, profound*

Are there any other examples of auto-antonyms of Latin? Did ancient writers mention this linguistic mechanism?

Comment: A famous such word is "altus", which can mean both "high" (of a mountain) and "deep" (of a sea).

Comment: [There's a separate question on the ambiguity of the prefix *in-*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11348/79).

Comment: @FlatAssembler If you read *altus* as "far in altitude", then it makes sense to be far in either direction (positive or negative altitude for a mountain or a sea) and the conflict is resolved. Some apparent conflicts from an English point of view are due differences in the logic of the two languages.

Comment: "*to make sth. dusty (although tagged as "archaic" in the dictionary)*" is still used in some senses. When dusting something for fingerprints, the object ends up covered in dust. And there are products, such as [*Fairy Dust* | Dusting Powder](https://www.lush.ca/en/fairy-dust/9999906460.html): "*This sweet-smelling, post-shower powder is the perfect finishing touch to keep your skin feeling light, fresh and fragrant.*".

Comment: @FlatAssembler **altus** can be classified in 4. above. It is common for some languages to use a non-directional word for bi-directional meanings while others use different words for each direction. Before learning English, I didn't think *to lend* and *to borrow* are different things because we use a single word for both. And I think it's how Romans thought about height and depth.

Comment: I once asked here about [**donec**](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/the-opposing-meanings-of-the-word-donec); in the comments I've added *recingo*; Generally, I guess many verbs with *re-* prefix are good candidates also like *retexo*.

Comment: for cat. 4 we can add *clamor*  that can be used both in negative (protest) and positive (applause)  senses.

Answer (score 4):

[*perlego*](https://gaffiot.org/73330) is a nice one in my opinion.

> **perlĕgō (pell-),** ēgī, ēctum, ĕre, tr.,
> **¶ 1** to scan with the eyes, to skim through: Virg. En. 6, 33; Ov. F. 1, 591
> **¶ 2** to read thoroughly, to read from beginning to end: Cic. Div. 1, 8; Att. 13, 44, 2; Cæs. C. 1, 19 ||
> to read aloud from start to finish: Pl. As. 748. ↣ form pell- Pl. As. 748; Bacch. 1037; Cic. *Att. 13, 44, 2.

Comment: Thank you for your example. Polysemy seems potential in some prefixed verbs. I can think of verbs with **re-**, which means undoing or doing again.